# A pandas dataframe column to pass as an argument of row level function to apply each value of the column to its respective row

Tags: python, pandas

![enter image description here][1]

I have a weird requirement to add a column similar to the below oracle query to apply on python dataframe. A pandas dataframe column to pass as an argument of row level function to apply each value of the column to its respective row.

```
select employee_id, first_name, last_name, substr(first_name, employee_id/employee_id, 3) test1 from hr.EMPLOYEES
```

The result has been attached in the below csv file.
I want to add a new column. So I wrote my pandas statement as below

```
EMPLOYEE.assign(test1=EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME.str.slice(EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID.apply(lambda x: x/x),4))
```

In this code I am using EMPLOYEE.EMPLOYEE_ID inside the slice function of EMPLOYEE.FIRST_NAME column.

my intention is if we think this as a variable

```
FIRST_NAME="Steven"
EMPLOYEE_ID=100
FIRST_NAME[int(EMPLOYEE_ID/EMPLOYEE_ID):4]
```

the output of this is
`'tev'`

#### If I apply the same concept on dataframe it is not working.

I am not getting the substring, instead I am getting NaN.
My Python output is as below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZN8x.png

The below is the output from SQL query.

```
    EMPLOYEE_ID   FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME TEST1
0           100       Steven       King   Ste
1           101        Neena    Kochhar   Nee
2           102          Lex    De Haan   Lex
3           103    Alexander     Hunold   Ale
4           104        Bruce      Ernst   Bru
5           105        David     Austin   Dav
6           106        Valli  Pataballa   Val
7           107        Diana    Lorentz   Dia
8           108        Nancy  Greenberg   Nan
9           109       Daniel     Faviet   Dan
10          110         John       Chen   Joh
11          111       Ismael    Sciarra   Ism
12          112  Jose Manuel      Urman   Jos
13          113         Luis       Popp   Lui
```

We can do it by creating a new column, but, as in SQL we can do it directly. I am expecting the same through pandas. Kindly help me on this.

My intended output is the same as above. But, I am writing a generic script that converts SQL query into pandas dataframe. I am stuck in achieving such scenarios where there is a column is being passed as a parameter of a row level function.

Comment: Please add the whole scenario, what you do you mean by "such scenarios where there is a column is being passed as a parameter of a row level function." ?

Comment: Hi @DaniMesejo, 
  I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df[['EMPLOYEE_ID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME']].apply(lambda i: i.FIRST_NAME[int(i.EMPLOYEE_ID/i.EMPLOYEE_ID):4], axis=1)
```

The above is giving me the answer. But it is slower than the other one

```
%timeit EMPLOYEE.apply(lambda i: i.FIRST_NAME[int(i.EMPLOYEE_ID/i.EMPLOYEE_ID):3], axis=1)
```

1.38 ms ± 58.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

```
%timeit EMPLOYEE[['EMPLOYEE_ID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME']].assign(pre=EMPLOYEE['FIRST_NAME'].str[1:4])
```

948 µs ± 22.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: Can anyone please give me a better solution than my approach?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
res = df[['EMPLOYEE_ID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME']].assign(pre=df['FIRST_NAME'].str[:3])
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
    EMPLOYEE_ID   FIRST_NAME  LAST_NAME  pre
0           100       Steven       King  Ste
1           101        Neena    Kochhar  Nee
2           102          Lex    De Haan  Lex
3           103    Alexander     Hunold  Ale
4           104        Bruce      Ernst  Bru
5           105        David     Austin  Dav
6           106        Valli  Pataballa  Val
7           107        Diana    Lorentz  Dia
8           108        Nancy  Greenberg  Nan
9           109       Daniel     Faviet  Dan
10          110         John       Chen  Joh
11          111       Ismael    Sciarra  Ism
12          112  Jose Manuel      Urman  Jos
13          113         Luis       Popp  Lui
```

To use it with [str.slice](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.slice.html) do:

```
res = df[['EMPLOYEE_ID', 'FIRST_NAME', 'LAST_NAME']].assign(pre=df['FIRST_NAME'].str.slice(stop=3))
```

where, stop is:

> stop int, optional Stop position for slice operation.

basically iterate one character at a time and stop in position 3 (non inclusive).

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response @Dani . But, I would like to know the possibility of using a column inside another column function. In my example I have used number column divide by itself it means the column returns 1 in each row. But, the apply function is evaluating my entire column and passing all the values for each row. instead can I restrict it to use the respective rows by index?

Comment: What is your intended output? I don't understand, but it seems that you want to use apply? Isn't the output of the query equal to the pandas code I just wrote?

Comment: My intended output is the same as you provided. But, I am writing a generic script that converts SQL query into pandas dataframe. I am stuck in achieving such scenarios where there is a column is being passed as a parameter of a row level function.

Comment: Your objective is quite complex, and is not what is expressed in the question and probably cannot be answer in a simple post

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I am sorry. My question is not quite straight forward.